# Test users to test a Facebook messenger chatbot

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

How can I have say 10-20 test users to test a messenger chatbot? Test users (the facebook supplied "fake" users) cannot be used at least so it seems.

I can add existing facebook accounts as testers, but they all have to become Facebook developers.

Something is seriously missing here.

Thank you for your help!